# How can I share my form with few controllers?

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a simple form, build with `formBuilder`. I need to use it in two controllers.
Can I simply share my form between two controllers for get access to it from them in Symfony?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions in the official documentation about form classes:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes

Then you can reuse the class in both controllers.

Comment: Thanks, but can I do it without creating new form class?

Comment: No, writting form classes is how you reuse forms in Symfony 2. What's the problem with creating the class?

Comment: There is no problem, I think maybe exists any other solution